# How to get Rails ActiveRecord db error messages with actual data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

The default message in database exceptions looks like this:

```
Couldn't find Business with 
  [WHERE "businesses"."agency_id" = $1 AND "businesses"."orig_key" = $2]
```

You can see, the actual values are elided, and only the unhelpful placeholders are shown. This is in test mode with Postgresql. The problem is that these messages in the log file aren't very helpful.